# Where is SSIS in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ssis

Where do I find the SSIS tools in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate? I'm at a new job so new computer / new setup / new everything. I can't find them anywhere! Is there a specific edition of SQL Server that includes these tools?

The DB is SQL Server 2005, SSMS is 2008, VS is 2010.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not yet available in Visual Studio 2010.

> "First of all, thank you to those customers who have offered feedback
> regarding how your work and productivity are impacted by Integration
> Services (SSIS) not yet being available in Visual Studio 2010. As
> developers ourselves, we certainly understand the frustration you have
> reported in having two Visual Studio instances installed and
> maintained on your development machines. While this side-by-side
> configuration works, it is certainly a less ideal solution to
> operating SSIS from within VS 2010. Unfortunately, the staggered ship
> cycles of the two products (VS and SSIS) and some convoluted
> dependencies did not allow us to reunite the development environments
> of both tools until the next version of SQL Server.
>
> Meanwhile, please be assured that SSIS projects continue to be
> supported by Visual Studio both now and into the foreseeable future.
> Until the next version of SQL Server, we will be happy to discuss with
> any Visual Studio 2010 customer ways in which they can optimize the
> interoperability of VS and SSIS. We apologize for any inconvenience
> and are committed to improving your user experience both now and in
> the future."

[Source](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-integration-services/bg-p/SSIS)

Comment: Why write VS2k10 instead of VS2010 if you have to type the same number of characters?  Not saving anything.

Comment: Apparently this is never going to be available.. :/